# Query to display the % of the failure rate

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have written this query to get my data, and all the data is fine.

I have one column which has either Pass Or Fail. I want to calculate the % of number of bookings that failed, and output it in a single value.

I will have to write another query to show that one number.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using - MySQL or MS SQL Server? Please update your tags accordingly.

Comment: Provide some sample table data

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this? You didn't really offer much to go on:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN trip_rating.rating <= 3 OR
           TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, booking_activity.activity_time, booking.pick_up_time) < 0 
    THEN 1.00 ELSE NULL END
    ) / COUNT(*)
FROM ...
```

Comment: This doesn't give me data in %, I tired multiplying with 100. Doesn't seem to work. Please help.

Comment: try multiplying with 100.00 decimal!!

Comment: It does, but lets say I have 10000 records, and I can see more than half of them failed - and this gives me 4.0% failed.

Comment: Perhaps it's all those extra joins. Can't say much since we don't know anything about your data.

Comment: I am trying to attach an image to the post. Nothing seems to be working @shawnt00

Comment: @learncode Maybe `< 0` isn't the right check. Do you really expect negative values there?

Comment: @shawnt00 I have edited the question, may be this can give you more idea.

Comment: Well what percentage do you get when you incorporate you're new logic? @learncode

Comment: Nothing more than 5.0, when it should give 50%.

Comment: Well try limiting your query to the BookingID values from your sample and see what that does. @learncode

Answer (score 0):

**Query**

```
select 
  concat(
    cast(
      (
        sum(case when t.Decision = 'Fail' then 1 else 0 end) / count(*)) * 100 
      as varchar(3)
  ), '%') as `fail rate`
from
(
  select ........
  case ........ end as Decision
)t;
```

Comment: I have added the data.

Comment: Keep your sql query as the subquery