# Query - To display the Failure rate %

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have written this query to get my data, and all the data is fine.

I have one column which has either Pass Or Fail. I want to calculate the % of number of bookings that failed, and output it in a single value.

I will have to write another query to show that one number.

For example : The below data, I have 4 bookings , out which 2 failed. So 50% is the failure rate. I am omitting some columns , in the display, but can be seen in the query.

Comment: Please review the thoughtful answers given below, thanks.

Comment: OP has asked the same question yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35323208/query-to-display-the-of-the-failure-rate

Answer (score 0):

Modify your original condition to the following.  Notice that there is no need to wrap your query in a subquery.

```
CONCAT(FORMAT((100 * SUM(CASE WHEN trip_rating.rating <= 3 AND
    (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,booking.pick_up_time,booking_activity.activity_time) -
     ROUND(booking_tracking_detail.google_adjusted_duration_driver_coming/60)) /
     TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,booking.pick_up_time,booking_activity.activity_time)*100 >= 15
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END) / COUNT(*)), 2), '%') AS failureRate
```

This will also format your failure rate in the format `50.0%`, with a percentage sign.

Comment: You need to be careful about the integer division.

Answer (score 0):

That's an aggregation over all records and simple math:

```
select count(case when decision = 'Fail' then 1 end) / count(*) * 100
from (<your query here>) results;
```

Explanation: `COUNT(something)` counts non null values. `case when decision = 'Fail' then 1 end` is 1 (i.e. not null) for failures and null otherwise (as null is the default for no match in CASE/WHEN ‐ you could as well write `else null end`  explicitly).